# Periodically set the userpoints for every user

Tags: userpoints

I would like to set the user points of members of my site to an x amount at the start of each month.
What would be the best way for this?

The closest I found so far was this:
http://drupal.org/node/549640

There are a few issues with this though:
1. It adds 5 points, instead of setting it to 5 universally
2. It uses a while loop which can take long if there are a lot of users

I am thinking of a quick and dirty UPDATE SQL query that does this in one go.

Answer (score 1):

you could extend the userpoints module to have some actions exposed to VBO then execute that periodically with Rules. Depends how much time you have, but it would be a nice addition to that module..

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered by me in the linked issue at http://drupal.org/node/549640 (comment 5-7). Quoting the answer here so that it can be found easier and the question can be marked as resolved.

> You can't just set the amount of points a user has to a fixed amount.
>   The total is just a summary of all transactions, you do not want to
>   set the amount without a corresponding transaction as this will lead
>   to a very confusing UI as the transactions will list something
>   different than the total a user currently has.
>
> What you need to do for each user is first to query how many points he
>   currently has and then give the missing amount of points.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $points_to_give = 500 - userpoints_get_current_points($uid);
> if ($points_to_give > 0) {
>   // Grant points here.
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> - Only process a fixed number of users on each cron run and only save
>     the time variable once you processed all users. This means that it
>     could take a few hours until all users have their points, depending on
>     how often you call cron.
> - Not using hook_crun() but for example create a custom script (e.g.
>     with drush) and then calling it separately. Or a custom page callback
>     that starts a batch process.

The follow-up comments are then about an alternative solution, which is to correct the number of points a user has when he logs in the first time in a new month.

Answer (score 0):

A rules-based solution. Here are the actions:

1. Load points of a user
2. Add a variable: Type: Integer, Value: 750
3. Calculate a value: [variable-added] minus [loaded-points]
4. Grant points to a user using the calculated value variable